# R-exams: drag and drop question type into Moodle

Tags: moodle, r-exams

My question is short: is it possible in `exams2moodle` use [drag&drop question type](https://docs.moodle.org/401/en/Drag_and_drop_onto_image_question_type) (or is it a plan)?

For example: with `tikzpicture` generate a circle with some lines (chord, secant, tangent, radius, diameter, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secant_line)) and students should drag&drop these lines names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment (R/exams version 2.4-0) this is not implemented. It is on our wishlist but there are no immediate plans to implement it soon.